# PHP memcached стал долго работать. Почему?

Tags: php, memcached, memcache

Всем добрый день! Есть сервер с относительно нагруженным сайтом. Работает давно без сбоев и глюков. Внезапно страницы стали подвисать, отклик по несколько секунд.
Разными путями вышел на проблему - стал долго отвечать сервер memcached.

Например, следующий код

```
    <?php
echo "Step 1 (" . microtime() . "):\r\n";
$memcached = new Memcached();
$memcached->addServer ("127.0.0.1", 11211 );

echo "Step 2 (" . microtime() . "):\r\n";

$memcached -> set ( 'abc', 123 );
echo "Step 3 (" . microtime() . "):\r\n";
$cached = $memcached->get('abc' );
echo "Step 4\r\n";
echo $cached;

?>
```

выводит это:

```
> Step 1 (0.55778200 1711614557)
Step 2 (0.55780900 1711614557):
Step 3 (0.56196000 1711614561):
Step 4
```

Между 2 и 3 шагами может быть пауза в пару секунд.

status мемкеша выводит это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Казалось, сервер не нагружен, но что значат эти too many open files..

Подскажите, в какую степь копать?

Comment: Тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29118446/too-many-open-files-when-using-memcached-for-sessions и тут https://askubuntu.com/questions/298615/how-to-increase-maximum-open-files-for-memcached-service читали?

Comment: читал, решения не нашел к сожалению